# Show that $\Bbb Z[\alpha,4/\alpha]/(2)$ is a direct product of three domains, where $\alpha^3+\alpha^2-2\alpha+8=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3+x^2-2x+8$. As part of another problem, I am trying to show that, in the ring $\Bbb Z[\alpha,4/\alpha]$, the ideal $(2)$ splits as a product of three distinct primes. This is equivalent to the fact that $\Bbb Z[\alpha,4/\alpha]/(2)$ is a product of three domains.

A useful fact is that the minimal polynomial of $4/\alpha$ is $x^3-x^2+2x+8$. The following all seems correct to me:
\begin{align}
\Bbb Z[\alpha,4/\alpha]/(2)&\cong \Bbb Z[x,y]/(2,x^3+x^2-2x+8,y^3-y^2+2y+8,xy-4)\\
&\cong \Bbb F_2[x,y]/(x^3+x^2,y^3+y^2,xy)\\
&\cong \Bbb F_2[x,y]/(x^2,y^3+y^2,xy)\cap(x+1,y^3+y^2,xy)\\
&=\Bbb F_2[x,y]/(x^2,y^3+y^2,xy)\oplus \Bbb F_2\\
&=\Bbb F_2\oplus \Bbb F_2[x,y]/(y^2,x^2,xy)\cap (y+1,x^2,xy)\\
&=\Bbb F_2\oplus \Bbb F_2\oplus \Bbb F_2[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2).
\end{align}
If it is unclear, I'm using the Chinese remainder theorem in a few places. Clearly the third component is not a domain, so something has gone wrong. Its possible that the first line is incorrect, and that you need another condition relating $x$ and $y$. For example, in the quotient, there is no difference between $2/\alpha$ and $4/\alpha$, which seems wrong.

The bigger context here is that $\Bbb Z[\alpha,4/\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$. This ring is interesting because Dedekind came up with a proof it is not monogenic. However, I am stuck on this detail, which is really just basic ring theory.

Comment: Do you have an integral basis? Is it just $\{1,\alpha,4/\alpha\}$ ?

Comment: @Lubin I’m pretty sure that’s correct; you can compute the discriminant to show that $\Bbb Z [\alpha, 4/\alpha]$ is the ring of integers and also show that $1,\alpha,4/\alpha$ is a basis.

Comment: Great question. Since $1, \alpha, 4/\alpha$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha, 4/\alpha]$, it seems like you must be missing some quadratic relations in the ideal defined in line $1$. In particular, $\alpha^{2}$ (for example) must be expressible as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $1, \alpha, 4/\alpha$, though it's not obvious to me what that linear combination should be. (One can deduce the relation $4\alpha^{2}+4\alpha-8 = 8(4/\alpha)$, e.g., but this vanishes mod $2$, and isn't strong enough.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim that sounds right. There’s gotta be something missing here. I will have to come back to this tomorrow though.

Comment: It hasta be true, ’cause the polynomial obviously factors into linears over $\Bbb Z_2$, courtesy of the Newton Polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing relations are $\alpha^2 = 2 - 2(4/\alpha) - \alpha$ and $(4/\alpha)^2 = 4/\alpha - 2\alpha - 2$.

These translate into $x^2 = 2 - 2y - x$ and $y^2 = y - 2x - 2$.

Modulo $2$ they become $x^2 = x$ and $y^2 = y$ (and these make the cubic relations superfluous).

So you have $$\begin{align*}\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x^2 - x, xy, y^2 - y) &= \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x,xy,y^2-y) \cap (x-1,xy,y^2-y) \\&\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x,xy,y^2-y)\oplus \mathbb{F}_2[x,y]/(x-1,xy,y^2-y)\\ & \cong \mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2-y)\oplus \mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y,y^2 - y)\\ &\cong \mathbb{F}_2 \oplus\mathbb{F}_2 \oplus\mathbb{F}_2.\end{align*}$$

Comment: Indeed, you have found two orthogonal idempotents in $R/(2)$, where $R$ is the ring of integers in the field, namely $e_1=\alpha$ and $e_2=4/\alpha$. The third is, of course, $e_3 = 1-e_1-e_2$. Thanks for this — I was going the long way ’round Robin Hood’s barn to try to find the idempotents, and it never occurred to me that they might be staring me in the face.

Comment: Thanks for writing this down! I wrote down these relations last night in a comment, but then deleted the comment after incorrectly computing $\mathbb{F}_{2}[x, y]/\langle x^{2}-x, xy, y^{2}-y \rangle$. (I incorrectly reduced both summands to $\mathbb{F}_{2}[y]/\langle y, y^{2}-y\rangle$.) It is a relief to see that things work out as expected after all!